# Second fundamental form as the derivative of Orthogonal projection operator

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, submanifold

I've been reading Lin and Wang's book titled ["The Analysis of Harmonic Maps and their Heat Flows"](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/6679#t=aboutBook) and found myself confused by the part where they express the second fundamental form of a surface as the derivative of the orthogonal projection map (screenshot).

I think what is going on is something like this: Suppose $\nu_{n+1},\nu_{n+2},...,\nu_L$ form the basis of the normal subspace to $N$ at the point $y\in N$. Then, the orthogonal projection operator into $T_yN$ can be expressed as
$$P(y)=I-\sum_{n+1}^L\nu_i\otimes\nu_i.$$

Taking a derivative, we get
$$\nabla P(y)=-\sum_{n+1}^L\nabla\nu_i\otimes\nu_i-\sum_{n+1}^L\nu_i\otimes\nabla\nu_i.$$
Take $X,Y\in T_yN$, then we have
$$\left\langle\nabla P(y)X,Y\right\rangle = -\sum_{n+1}^L\left\langle\nabla\nu_i X,Y\right\rangle\nu_i = -\sum_{n+1}^L A^i(X,Y)\nu_i$$

I'm not sure if this is correct. Can someone provide a proof of this result?
[image: Screenshot from Section 1.3 of 1]